# Jekyll collection for loop stopped working

Tags: jekyll

Suddenly, using jekyll 3.4.3 for a while now, this loop for rendering collection items has stopped working for me...

```
{% for work in site.work %}
                    {% if work.featured %}
                        {% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo:2 %}
                        {% if mod == 0 %}
                            <a href="{{work.url}}"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 featured-work">
                                <div class="featured-work-title">{{work.title|replace: " ","</br>"}}</div>
                                <div class="featured-work-image" style="background-image: url(/images/{{work.image}});"></div>
                            </div></a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="{{work.url}}"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 featured-work">
                                <div class="featured-work-title">{{work.title|replace: " ","</br>"}}</div>
                                <div class="featured-work-image" style="background-image: url(/images/{{work.image}});"></div>
                            </div></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my _config.yaml

```
collections:
   work:
      output: true
      permalink: /work/:path/
```

And this is a sample of one of the items

```
---
layout: work
featured: true
title: Eluu.ee
link: http://eluu.ee
punchline: What does it take to sell a toy.
image: eluu.jpg
disciplines:
    - Website
    - Ecommerce
    - Voog
year: Ongoing
---

In late 2016, I .....
```

Nothing gets put to the page, no errors are given.. when outputting site.collections.work alone, all the content IS there.... What's wrong?

Comment: Code seems to be fine, any errors with after accesing the page with `bundle exec jekyll s --trace`?

Comment: @marcanuy Nope, absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to jekyll 3.5 worked.

Comment: I was having the same problem. I figured setting a future date prevents it from getting posted